# Best way to deal with and not delete expired relationships?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a database that will be updated regularly with changing relationships.  I'd like to store new data and old, and be able to pull just the new when I need it.  Example:

Items and their price.  Price may change for an item, but I'd like to keep note of the old prices, while still being able to pull only the currently relevant prices.

Best way I can think to do this now is to have effective start and end dates.  So I could query to pull only relationships that have yet to 'expire' if you will.  Is there a better or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Effective and end dates are pretty much the standard way of storing type 2 dimension information -- and that is what you are describing.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2014 and later, you can use TEMPORAL tables which is for exact the same purpose

Answer (score 0):

The best I could think of is Creating a Trigger.

1. Add a column named flag to the table, indicating if it is 'new' or 'old'. You will have only one new row for a group/relationship at a time
2. Add a column named updated date , that would be the date when it is updated. (If you are interested in knowing the most recent old data)

Create a trigger that would trigger on inserting a new row in to the table

1. Update the flag to 'old' , for any row with 'new' flag for that particular combination of item and price.
2. And update the updated date to sysdate

So you will have one new row for a combination. When you need just new data mention flag = 'new'. And all old rows will have a updated date stating when it became old price

Comment: Having Start and End date is much better. It's not clear what is the benefit of your solution. Can you clarify?

Comment: We can have a flag in the table that can have two possible values 'new' and 'old'.
For newly inserted rows we will have the flag column as 'new'
There will be a trigger on the table, which triggers for each insert (say we are inserting a row for item 'Abc' ) and it updates all the existing rows for item 'Abc' with the flag 'old' and also sets the updated_date column to current date (meaning it's updated now). So when we just need the new records we can fetch with a condition flag = 'new'. We can also refer the 'old' records and use the updated_date to know how old it is

Comment: So, as you say the flag shows what row is current and we have a date column for each row that says when the row expired. In this case if we want to find the active row for specific date, I think the query will not be straight forward specially when we are joining the tables

Comment: if we want to find the active row for specific date, we can query based on the updated_date. No?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table for Price History just like one of the ERP in the market.

> PRICE_HIST
>
> This table contains a history of all price changes that have ever been
>   applied within the system. History is kept on this table forever by
>   SKU/store combination.

```
Column                Nulls ?       Type
------                -------       ----
TRAN_TYPE             NOT NULL      NUMBER (2, 0)
REASON                NULL          NUMBER (2, 0)
EVENT                 NULL          VARCHAR2 (6)
ITEM                  NOT NULL      VARCHAR2 (25)
LOC                   NOT NULL      NUMBER (10, 0)
LOC_TYPE              NULL          VARCHAR2 (1)
UNIT_COST             NULL          NUMBER (20, 4)
UNIT_RETAIL           NULL          NUMBER (20, 4)
SELLING_UNIT_RETAIL   NULL          NUMBER (20, 4)
SELLING_UOM           NULL          VARCHAR2 (4)
ACTION_DATE           NOT NULL      DATE
MULTI_UNITS           NULL          NUMBER (12, 4)
MULTI_UNIT_RETAIL     NULL          NUMBER (20, 4)
MULTI_SELLING_UOM     NULL          VARCHAR2 (4)
POST_DATE             NULL          DATE
```

> ACTION_DATE
>
> Contains the date on which the price change went effect.